# Create connection mongose in nestjs got "undefined"

Tags: mongoose, plugins, nestjs

I have an app, I want to connect to MongoDB, I follow nestjs document. Use a plugin "mongoose-unique-validator" below my code

```
 @Module({
  imports: [
    ConfigModule.forRoot({
      isGlobal: true,
      envFilePath: `.env.${process.env.NODE_ENV}`,
    }),
    MongooseModule.forRootAsync({
      useFactory: async (configService: ConfigService) => ({
        uri: configService.get<string>('MONGO_URI'),
        autoIndex: true,
        useNewUrlParser: true,
        useUnifiedTopology: true,
        connectionFactory: (connection: MongooseConnection) => {
          // Global plugins
          connection.plugin(mongooseUniqueValidator);
          connection.plugin(mongoosePaginate);
          connection.plugin(mongooseToJson);
          return connection;
        },
      }),
      inject: [ConfigService],
    }),
  ],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [AppService],
})
```

But it didn't produce the result, it keep saying 'First param to `schema.plugin()` must be a function, got "undefined"'

my package json:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@nestjs/common": "^9.0.0",
    "@nestjs/config": "^2.2.0",
    "@nestjs/core": "^9.0.0",
    "@nestjs/mapped-types": "*",
    "@nestjs/mongoose": "^9.1.1",
    "@nestjs/platform-express": "^9.0.0",
    "@nestjs/platform-socket.io": "^9.2.1",
    "@nestjs/websockets": "^9.2.1",
    "helmet": "^6.0.1",
    "mongoose": "6.4.3",
    "mongoose-paginate-v2": "^1.7.1",
    "mongoose-unique-validator": "^2.0.3",
    "openai": "^3.1.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.13",
    "rimraf": "^3.0.2",
    "rxjs": "^7.2.0"
  },
```

Any tip? Thanks.

Comment: How are you importing the plugins? You may be using a default import when it should be a named one, or vice versa